# Is there anyone who has Canon MX435 printer. No driver for Linux

Tags: printing, canon

There is Mac and Windows drivers only. I tried that tar.gz file http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100412601.html
Nothing happened. Usb cable not connected. Trying to print over wifi.

How can I use MX435 from Ubuntu?

Comment: the file you linked to did all the work! it is exactly what you needed. just open the terminal, navigate to the extracted folder, and run the install.sh file. worked for me:)

Comment: Does wi-fi printing work?

Comment: @Takkat I'm not convinced that this is a dupe as the MX435 isn't listed in the answer quoted. It may well work though. Can you confirm? I don't have one...

Comment: @ElderGeek The list from the ppa answer (as was the answer prior to my edit BTW) is outdated. Unfortunately I have no idea where to get an updated list. Still, people can follow my answer below there to install the MX43x driver from Canon. It's always the same procedure for all Canon printers... hence I believe it is easier to maintain all these question in a master canonical question - I chose the one I linked to because it had most upvotes and views but added another answer for cases like this one.

Comment: @Takkat Sorry, I missed that final answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that webpage you posted, there *is* a Linux driver. It's nice to find Linux support from manufacturers. The bad part is there's no easy installer provided.

In case you didn't know already, a `.tar.gz` file is a compressed directory in a file, somewhat like a `.zip`.

What you want to do first is extract the .tar.gz file. You can do this by double clicking the downloading cnijfilter-mx430series-3.70-1-deb.tar.gz file and selecting "Extract". After you extract the contents of the archive, navigate to the extracted directory. Inside you will find `install.sh`. Double click it - Ubuntu will then ask whether you want to run the program or not. Say that you want to run the program in a terminal.

Tell us if it works, or if the terminal says anything unusual. If it says something along the lines of `must be run as superuser` or `need root privileges`, then you'll need to run it as root. For that...you'd need to navigate to the directory in a terminal and run `sudo install.sh`.

Comment: I tried with usb cable and with wifi, but nothing happened. It didn't work. By the way copier and scanner function works fine.

Comment: Please give us the steps you took to come up with the conclusion of "it didn't work." We can't help you unless we know what you did (or more often, didn't) do.

Comment: Sorry for latency. Its messed up right now. First I tried without driver, then tried with three different driver file. Now, I want to clear everything and start from stratch. How can I undo all of  what I've done? By the way printer is okey. It worked with windows.

Answer (score -1):

The URL http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100412601.html
does contain a driver.

I also have an Canon MX 435 that i have had trouble installing on my Ubuntu 12-04.

After installing this driver the printer works so far.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you installed it?

Comment: It actually a long a messy story. I have a windows system as well that did the main installation and put the printer on the wireless network. After that I rand the installation script that is linked in the answer. After specifying the printer to we wifi (upon being asked) it detected it and seems to have installed proper drivers.